# Are there any actions called when the system dropdown on an HTML dropdown becomes visible or blurs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, handler

I am aware that an `onFocus`, and `onBlur` action exists, but I can't find any hooks when the system's dropdown shows in the HTML dropdown `<select>` tag.

As an example, I have a `<select>` input where I would like to turn the background pink when the system's dialogue is showing. Having a CSS `focus` selector requires you to explicitly click out of the system dialogue THEN click out again from the `<select>` form to change the color..

Here is a fiddle of this behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/carlopascual/n5u2wwjg/92994/ .

I hope we can get to the bottom of this!

Comment: your fiddle is working perfect to me (using Chrome 67). Even a TAB key will cause the lost of focus, so it returns to white background.

Comment: I guess you can use click event, we know that the dropdown will be visible only if the click event is fired in the select tag.

Comment: you can always use the events that are `focus`, `blur` and `change`

Answer (score 2):

if you don't mind switching to select2 https://select2.org/ it is pretty easy

```
$('#example').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select a month',
});

$('#example').on('select2:open', function(e) {
  $('.select2-search').css('background-color', 'pink');
  $('.select2-results').css('background-color', 'pink');
});

$('#example').on('select2:close', function(e) {
  $('.select2-search').css('background-color', 'white');
  $('.select2-results').css('background-color', 'white');
});
```

here is a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/rLmztr2d/2476/

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger onblur event after selecting an element in the drop-down.

```
$('.className').trigger('blur');
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `:active` ?

```css
select {
  background: white;
}

select:active {
  background: pink;
}

select:active option:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Lorem</option>
  <option>Ipsum</option>
  <option>Dolor</option>
</select>
```

Also, to manipulate different options, use `select:active option.specific` selector.